# Web service SOAP integration

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

Im a bit confused. I have a WS which has different "message format" than another WS I have seen in the past.

The vendor provided me a set of messages which they can accecpt (I have tested in SoapUI and it really works - well)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:urn="urn:SAMPLE">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:CustomEnvelope>
```

The problem is, that in place where `CustomEnvelope` is used I would expect any method name (something like `urn:calculateSum`).

When I have tried to generate java client using Axis2, than in case od ADB databinding method I got uncompileable code. When I have used another one, I had on my Stub object only method named (for example) `calculateSum` and generated message doesn't correspond to the expected schema (instead od `CustomEnvelope`) there was used `calculateSum`.

My question is. Do you know what this strange format means? And have you any suggestion how to integrate such strange WS? I think about creating the whole XML using JAXB (vendor has provided a XSD files) and sending to the WS or creating SOAPMessages using standard Java API. But I am not sure what is there the best sollution.

Thanks, Ondrej

Comment: If the web service is represented by a WSDL file, you would probably find it quite helpful to generate classes from that WSDL using the [wsimport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/wsimport.html) tool that comes with every JDK.  It will not only generate JAXB classes for you, it will generate a service class and port classes for all of the operations, complete with `throws` clauses for the faults.

Comment: Hi @VRR, you were right here. The wsimport works fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue during the Axis 2 client side stub generation, which gives you uncompileable code. Error is at the `ADBDataSource` class.

If this is your problem then here is the solution. What I did in my project, we are using WebSphere as the web application server and it contains a jar file `(Something)ThinClient.jar` in the class path of your project.
Now this jar also contains same class called `ADBDataSource` but its an abstract class. Which conflicts with our stubs because it creates object of `ADBDataSource`.

I suggest try to find out that do you have a such jar or not.

**Solution**

Remove  `(Something)ThinClient.jar` or one which has same class from your class path.

If removing  `(Something)ThinClient.jar` creates problem, then change the approach and use Jax-Ws insteadof Axis 2, which is part of Java it self. (This is what I did.)